# PHP parsing PDO Fetch into JSON

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, pdo

Im trying to get a PHP file to execute a MySQL query and return the results in a JSON format to a Javascript function.

My php:

```
require_once("class.user.php");
$auth_user = new USER();

$stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("
        SELECT *
        FROM projects;
");                       
$stmt->execute();
$results=$stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

file_put_contents('filename.json',json_encode($results));

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($results);
```

My Javascript:

```
function getProjectNames(){
var dataList = document.getElementById('projectNames');
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        IsJsonString(this.response);
        //document.getElementById("projectsresults").innerHTML = this.response;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET","getProjectNames.php",true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
function IsJsonString(str) {
    try {
        document.write(JSON.stringify(str));
    } catch (e) {
        document.write("is not valid JSON" + e);
        return false;
    }
    //document.write("is valid JSON");
    return true;
}
```

Now the javascript will display

```
[{"Project_ID":"1","Name":"Software Project 1"},{"Project_ID":"2","Name":"Software Project 2"}]
```

However if i try to parse this as JSON and access a variable then it either comes back with 'undefined' or 'null'. I have tried 'JSON.stringify'  and that returns

```
"\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n[{\"Project_ID\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"Software Project 1\"},{\"Project_ID\":\"2\",\"Name\":\"Software Project 2\"}]\r\n"
```

So i think something must be going wrong between the PHP encoding the JSON and the Javascript fetching it. I have ran out of ideas and any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Added the rest of PHP and Javascript code

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Can you give the code you using toe access the json response? I suspect there's an error there.

Comment: Are you trying to access the result of `JSON.parse()` outside the `onreadystatechange` function? That won't work because it's asynchronous.

Comment: [{"Project_ID":"1","Name":"Software Project 1"},{"Project_ID":"2","Name":"Software Project 2"}]

where is it displayed in an element or?

Comment: @ŽeljkoKrnjić This code displays the raw JSON: `document.getElementById("projectsresults").innerHTML = this.response;`

Comment: Well i did the same and successfully parsed it into javascript list

JSON.parse(document.getElementById("projectresults").innerHTML));

Comment: @ŽeljkoKrnjić That's why we need to see the code that's failing, because he's obviously doing something wrong.

Comment: @LazyAlpine you should post the code where you are parsing the response  so we can help.

Comment: Ive added the full functions for Javascript and PHP. If i try to use JSON.parse on 'this.response' to set the inner html of a element then i get  a console error: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0'

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead of your IsJsonString function:

```
function IsJsonString(response){
    var parsedJson = JSON.parse(response);
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(parsedJson);

    document.getElementById("projectNames").innerHTML = jsonString;
}
```

and pass it `this.response` as a parameter.

Comment: Still erroring out over the JSON.parse with the error : 'Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0'. Seems when i initially encode in the PHP that its not doing it correctly.

Comment: Try accessing the php page which outputs the json manually, copy it and go to this website: http://jsonlint.com/ and paste your json there it will tell you if the json is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late, but the problem is still relevant to many.
The first thing to do is to verify that the PDO drive created a correct UTF8 encoded formatting of the JSON object

Server side...

```
    <?php
    try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbAnme', "user",  "pass!",
                  array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));//here
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


   //Query
echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);


  } catch (PDOException $e) {
      print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
      die();
  }
    ?>
```

client side...

```
var myObj =[];

     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

          myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
//now you can access to properties...
       
       console.log(myObj.projectsProperty);
       console.log(JSON.strinify(myObj));
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET","getProjectNames.php",true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
```